# How to extract matching groups when searching regex in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Am using elasticsearch to index some data (**a text article**) and mapped it as

```
"article": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
```

, then I use `regexp` queries to search for some matches, the result returns the correct documents, but is there a way to also return the `matching groups`/`text` which triggered the regex hit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use highlghting functionality of Elasticsearch.

Lets consider below is your sample document:

```json
{
  "article":"Elasticsearch Documentation"
}
```

**Query:**

```json
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "article": "el.*ch"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "article": {}
    }
  }
}
```

**Response**

```json
{
        "_index" : "index1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "cHzAH4IBgPd6xUeLm9QF",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "article" : "Elasticsearch Documentation"
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "article" : [
            "<em>Elasticsearch</em> Documentation"
          ]
        }
      }
```

Comment: seems it works for single term, but if I do it for `keyword`, it won't work .. like in your example if I try this regex ... `"article": "el.*ch doc"`, what does it it produce ?

Comment: I have created a follow-up question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73073875/how-to-highlight-regexp-in-elasticsearch-to-with-patterns-that-include-spaces

Comment: @Exorcismus This query `"article": "el.*ch doc"` will not return any document as wildcard work based term and keyword field is not analyzed. If you want to get result then you need to try `El.*ch Documentation` this query then only you will get result on `keyword` type field.