# How to highlight regexp in elasticsearch to with patterns that include spaces

Tags: elasticsearch

Am trying to use regexp in elasticsearch to find some patterns and highlight it, the pattern am trying to find contain spaces,
I also used `keyword` as to not analyze the text

```
{
  "type": "text",
    "fields": {
       "keyword": {
         "type": "keyword"
          }
      }
  }
```

the exact pattern is `".*( [a-zA-Z]( |,|.)){3,5}.*"` the query looks like this

```
{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "transcript_data.transcript.keyword": {
              "value": ".*( [a-zA-Z]){3,5}.*"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "transcript_data.transcript.keyword": {}
    }
  }
}
```

the highlight seems to highlight the whole document (start to end) eventhough the pattern lies in the middle of text.

to clarify, consider the below difference between the 2 images

[image]
**V.S.**
[image]

for example
`It's it's it's a steal. A hot eight mining and b k k t. I think these have went too` the output should be `<em>b k k t</em>` I get ... `<em>It's it's it's a steal. A hot eight mining and b k k t. I think these have went too</em>` and I believe this because the `.*` but this also seem to be the way regex work in ES, what am doing wrong ?

Comment: I have tried example given by you but i am getting zero result even for keyword field. I am not sure how you are getting highlghting. are you trying multipul query clause ? did you just try regexp query ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot search for `text` type of field when regex have white space because text field are analzyed and it is split into multipul tokens. So when you do search on text field with whitespace in regex then it will not return any result.

Currently you are trying to search keyword, type of field which is not analyzed field and that's why you are able to search it. Also, it is highlighting entire field because keyword field is not analyzed and it will store  entire single value.

You can use `"require_field_match": "false"` in highlighting if you want to search on other field and highlight on different field but this will also not work in your case.

You can try out `shingle` another and then try to search on keyword field and highlight on `shingle` field, but I am not sure if this will fit your usecase completelty.

Comment: please check edits